# Django RAW SQL, named parameters

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a complex query, with some inner joins, a little `where` clause and `HAVING` clause too, this is for a report.

In this case, I can't use Model.objects.raw, so instead, I'm using `cursor.execute(sql)`. My question is with my parameters. I have 20 parameters and some of them are repeated (company_id in every inner join).

Using a dict and %(key)s don't work here when using cursor.execute, it only works with Model.object.raw.

How can I name parameter, to just pass it once? Or is there a method to sanitize my entire query, avoiding SQL injection?

Pass all the 20 parameters and repeating them in order in a list is not readable.

Comment: Which database?

Comment: @serg working with MySQL

Comment: How doesn't it work? Are you calling cursor.execute(sql, dict_with_named_params)?

Comment: Cursory attempt and can't get it to work either. It seems to just sub in the first char of the param. Tried using the `:name` system of formatting and still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

According to Django documentation this is the right way to do it but WARNING it won't work on Sqlite

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * from Bla where id = %(some_id)s', {"some_id":1})
```

Comment: Doesn't work on MSSQL (using [mssql-django](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django) )